# Angle between Fleming-Viot type 3-particle system

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Consider $(X^1,X^2,X^3)\in (0,\infty)^3$ with each particle starting at $1$ and moving independently according to Brownian motion until random time $\tau_1:=\min \lbrace t>0: X_{t-}^1\wedge X_{t-}^2\wedge X_{t-}^3=0\rbrace$ when one of them would hit $0$. This particle jumps uniformly to one of the other two. Aterwards all three positive particles again move independently according to Brownian motion unil $\tau_2$ and so on.

The process $\arctan \frac{X_{\tau_n-}^1\vee X_{\tau_n-}^2\vee X_{\tau_n-}^3}{\min \lbrace X_{\tau_n-}^1, X_{\tau_n-}^2,X_{\tau_n-}^3\rbrace \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace}$ on $(0,\pi/4]$ of angles between the two positive particles when the third one is jumping converges to some invariant distribution. Here is a numerically obtained plot of the (Lebesgue) density function (by discretization): [image: plot of density]

The picture highly suggests point symmetry at $(\pi/8, 4/\pi)$.

If one would have two independent Brownian motions conditioned not to hit $0$ (so they behave like 3-dimensional Bessel processes), their angle converged in time against the law with distribution function $\varphi\mapsto\frac{32}{\pi} \, \sin^2 \varphi \,\cos^2  \varphi$ on $(0,\pi/4]$, so the same symmetry property holds. (That means, the positive distance of the angle to $\pi/8$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,\pi/8)$.)

I would like to know whether there is an intuitive reason for this in either case. Also I am interested in anything that can be said about the stationary distribution of the angles of the original particle process at jumping times. The integral equation is $$
f(\varphi) =  \frac {4} {\pi} \, \sin \varphi \cos \varphi \int_0^{\pi/4}\sin \varphi_0 \cos \varphi_0  \biggl( \cos \varphi_0 \sqrt{1+\cos^2 \varphi_0} \Bigl( \frac {1} {4\cos^4\varphi_0 \sin^2 \varphi + \cos^4 \varphi} + \frac {1} {4\cos^4\varphi_0 \cos^2 \varphi + \sin^4 \varphi} + \frac {1} {1-4\cos^4\varphi_0 \sin^2 \varphi \cos^2 \varphi}\Bigr) + \sin\varphi_0 \sqrt{1+\sin^2 \varphi_0} \Bigl( \frac {1} {4\sin^4\varphi_0 \cos^2 \varphi + \sin^4 \varphi} + \frac {1} {4\sin^4\varphi_0 \sin^2 \varphi + \cos^4 \varphi} + \frac {1} {1-4\sin^4\varphi_0 \sin^2 \varphi \cos^2 \varphi}\Bigr) \biggr) \, f(\varphi_0) \, d\varphi_0,
$$ or, equivalently $$
g(z) = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^1 z_0 \sqrt{1-z_0^2} \Bigl( \frac{1}{4z_0^2\,(1-z)+z^2} + \frac{1}{4z_0^2\,z+(1-z)^2} + \frac{1}{1-4z_0^2\,z(1-z)} \Bigr) \, g(z_0)\, dz_0.$$